# How can I assign an id to an item in a list which can be viewed if I pick an item randomly?

Tags: python, list

I don't know hot to explain it very well, but I need to somehow set an id like 1 to the first item in the list. I am aware of :

```py
my_list = ["hello", "how","are","you","?"]
print(my_list[1])
```

would return `how`, but what I'm trying to do is a method to reset a password without an e-mail, and using a set of 12 random words given when the  user signs up.

```py
import random
import hashlib
def verify_menmonic_written(mnemonic_hash, words2verify=6):
    """Verify if user has written down mnemonic
    Chooses random words to verify if the user has written down the mnemonic. 
    """
    words = []
    while words2verify >= 0:
        for i in range(6):
            hash = random.choice(mnemonic_hash)
            if hash in words:
                pass
            else:
                words2verify -=1
                words.append(hash)
    return words    

hash_list = ['76205fd077642109bcffa636100630b08f569d1e', '991eccffe16f2da8f9cb10be8b91cfc9d07b724a', 'b2fc50740727fc6684a2574a64f54235fe2897cc', '285f9a003f671c2486a3f87ea1ad5e37699ebc38', '1804bfc99ddcc4d91052565084072902434ae9ba', '02ce10990a66b7fb2b8e456a761b8faaf0ae701d', '067cb2b4d11bea7491255dacecc3a42a97530354', 'ddcb4be46283a08885a8347abe4142e6630f62e8', 'd525fbd8282f3c0c13abdce29b8db6db950e00a4', '516626bf8a5006ecce1803eeb6a747182000d4f8', '9bf235d7e9a3d65fad30c2400b4003eea317b619', '46d350ed4cb25f0b60c0951eb0858fcf9300346d']

print("Verified :",verify_menmonic_written(mnemonic_hash=hash_list))
```

To verify if the user has written down the words, i would like to pick 6 random words, but I messed up the code because I want to check if a word (hash) is repeated. Then I would like to be able to record the order, like `my_list = [hash1, hash2, etc.]` to know which letter goes 1st 2nd and so on, so I can say "Write the 1st, 4th and 8th word of the mnemonic" and then check if the input matches the word hash.

Comment: So you need to assign an id / number to each word in your list?

Comment: yes, that is what i need

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just need to use a dictionary and put each hash as in python

```
hashes = {
    "Hash1": "position",
}
```